# App crashes when BackButton is pressed

Tags: android, service, mqtt, paho

i am using `Paho Android Service API` and I onnect in `onResume` and disconnect in `onPause`. At run time, I can `subscribe` from the device and see the `published` messages from the PC through `mosquitto Broker`. when I press he `BackButton` the App crahses and shows the below `logcat` errors.

kindly please let me know how to solve this issue.

**to Note**:

1_since i am using `Paho Android Service API` i imported the required libraries into the project. And
  within the `application` element of the manifest file of my project i have added this line

2_i am not registering any receivers in my frament, the receiver in included in the library i 
  imported to use Paho API

```
<!-- Mqtt Service -->
    <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
    </service>
```

**LogCat**:

```
     Activity com.example.mqtt_test_00.MessaginActivity   
    has leaked IntentReceiver org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient@43075698 that was   
    originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity   
    com.example.mqtt_test_00.MessaginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver  
    org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient@43075698 that was originally registered here.  
    Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.
    <init>(LoadedApk.java:814)
    at 
    android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
    at 
    android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1762)
    at  
    android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1742)
    at  
    android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1736)
    at 
    android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:478)
    at org
    .eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.registerReceiver(MqttAndroidClient.java:410)

    at  
    org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.connect(MqttAndroidClient.java:388)
    at   
    com.example.mqtt_test_00.Sub_Frag$5.onClick(Sub_Frag.java:98)
 android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity 
    com.example.mqtt_test_00.MessaginActivity has leaked ServiceConnection 
    org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient$MyServiceConnection@430756f0 that was 
    originally bound here
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>
    (LoadedApk.java:988)
    at 
    org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.connect(MqttAndroidClient.java:385)
    at   
    com.example.mqtt_test_00.Sub_Frag$5.onClick(Sub_Frag.java:98 )
```

Comment: unregister the service ,before your backpressed the class ,used the unregister in onpause() method

Answer (score 1):

The logcat is pretty clear about the situation. It seems like you're not unregistering a receiver.

You should do that by calling unregisterReceiver() in one of the life-cycle methods(onPause(), onStop()) your Activity has.

```
unregisterReceiver(yourReceiver);
```

Where yourReceiver is most probably an instance of MqttAndroidClient(per logcat output)

Comment: i am not registering any receivers in my frament, the receiver in included in the library i imported to use Paho API

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:

```
11-21 13:26:51.703: E/ActivityThread(28310): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity   
com.example.mqtt_test_00.MessaginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver  
org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient@43075698 that was originally      registered here.  
Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

your not unregister service in same class ,so your got this issue,try like this,

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try
    {
       unregisterReceiver(this.intentReceiver);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not registering any receivers in my frament, the receiver in included in the library i imported to use Paho API

Comment: your logcat shows the message receiver service implemented and then after your exit from the class your not unregister that service ,

Comment: ok,your showing the service in manifest file and where using the register intentservice

Comment: follow this link:http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/commit?id=2b9f4839a8ed8ed27680653e1de8d14610d46746  ,this link may help you know the register

Answer (score 0):

I would not repeat what aother members have suggested and recommnded, but the only thing I would like to say is that, calling `client.disconnect` would `unregister` the `service`. Have you called `disconnect`?

Answer (score 0):

MqttAndroidClient has method named unregisterResources which will unregister receiver if any.

The usage is something likes this

MqttConnection connection = MqttConnections.getInstance(this).getConnection(clientHandle);
connection.getClient().unregisterResources();